# Create a SQL query to retrieve most recent records

Tags: sql, t-sql, derived-table

I am creating a status board module for my project team. The status board allows the user to to set their status as in or out and they can also provide a note. I was planning on storing all the information in a single table ... and example of the data follows:

```
Date               User         Status    Notes
-------------------------------------------------------
1/8/2009 12:00pm   B.Sisko      In        Out to lunch    
1/8/2009 8:00am    B.Sisko      In  
1/7/2009 5:00pm    B.Sisko      In    
1/7/2009 8:00am    B.Sisko      In    
1/7/2009 8:00am    K.Janeway    In   
1/5/2009 8:00am    K.Janeway    In    
1/1/2009 8:00am    J.Picard     Out       Vacation
```

I would like to query the data and return the most recent status for each user, in this case, my query would return the following results:

```
Date               User         Status    Notes
-------------------------------------------------------  
1/8/2009 12:00pm   B.Sisko      In        Out to lunch    
1/7/2009 8:00am    K.Janeway    In   
1/1/2009 8:00am    J.Picard     Out       Vacation
```

I am try to figure out the TRANSACT-SQL to make this happen? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Aggregate in a <strike>subquery</strike> derived table and then join to it.

```
 Select Date, User, Status, Notes 
    from [SOMETABLE]
    inner join 
    (
        Select max(Date) as LatestDate, [User]
        from [SOMETABLE]
        Group by User
    ) SubMax 
    on [SOMETABLE].Date = SubMax.LatestDate
    and [SOMETABLE].User = SubMax.User
```

Comment: This is called a derived table.

Comment: Be careful if the derived table ends up with duplicates for {LatestDate,User}

Comment: Never rely on uniqueness unless the database guarantees it; i would never recommend this approach over the answer by SQLMenace, as accidental duplicates in the result can cause quite unexpected downstream behavior. (best example of failure here is a scripted update which causes a couple of state changes to land at the same time)

Answer (score 90):

another way, this will scan the table only once instead of twice if you use a subquery

only sql server 2005 and up

```
select Date, User, Status, Notes 
from (
       select m.*, row_number() over (partition by user order by Date desc) as rn
       from [SOMETABLE] m
     ) m2
where m2.rn = 1;
```

Comment: Magic, I was able to solve tricky query involving joining 3 tables and selecting only latest entry for each type based on this code. Thank you!

Comment: This has the same cost in execution plan as the accepted answer but when you need to group by multiple columns for example orgID,Month,Year, this answer is semantically cleaner.

Comment: this randomly selects the record out of all records equal first according to the ordering.

Comment: @AndrewHill Maybe your comment was before `(partiation by my_pk order by event_time desc)`?  This does what OP asked, but allows sort criteria to be on non-join column, which MAX() with GROUP BY does not.

Answer (score 12):

The derived table would work, but if this is SQL 2005, a CTE and ROW_NUMBER might be cleaner:

```
WITH UserStatus (User, Date, Status, Notes, Ord)
as
(
SELECT Date, User, Status, Notes, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY User ORDER BY Date DESC)
FROM [SOMETABLE]
)

SELECT User, Date, Status, Notes from UserStatus where Ord = 1
```

This would also facilitate the display of the most recent x statuses from each user.

Answer (score 8):

Another easy way:

```
SELECT Date, User, Status, Notes  
FROM Test_Most_Recent 
WHERE Date in ( SELECT MAX(Date) from Test_Most_Recent group by User)
```

Comment: Won't this query go wrong if two users update their status at the same time, but that time isn't the latest activity for one of them?

Comment: Mahesh, you need to update your answer taking into account @SooDesuNe's comment.

Comment: Dont use SELECTS in WHERE clauses if you can help it. Unless its a one time thing you need to look up. If this is going in a stored proc, it greatly increases the time to return results. Especially on large tables.

Answer (score 1):

Add an auto incrementing Primary Key to each record, for example, UserStatusId.

Then your query could look like this:

```
select * from UserStatus where UserStatusId in
(
    select max(UserStatusId) from UserStatus group by User
)
```

Date               User         Status    Notes